# what does MajorAxisLength property in regionprop matlab function mean?

Tags: matlab

I am using regionprop function in matlab to get MajorAxisLength of an image. I think logically this number should not be greater than sqrt(a^2+b^2) in wich a abd b are the width and heigth of the image. but for my image it is. My black and white image contains a black circle in the center of the image. I think this is strange. Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711784/computing-object-statistics-from-the-second-central-moments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code of `regionprops` (subfunction `ComputeEllipseParams`), you see that they use the second moment to estimate the ellipsoid radius. This works very well for ellipsoid-shaped features, but not very well for features with holes. The second moment increases if you remove pixels from around the centroid (which is, btw, why they make I-beams). Thus, the bigger the 'hole' in the middle of your image, the bigger the apparent ellipsoid radius.

In your case, you may be better off using the `extrema` property of regionprops, and to calculate the largest radius from there.