# Matlab operator **

Tags: matlab

I was checking a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711784/computing-object-statistics-from-the-second-central-moments/1712019#1712019) here.

What does the operator ** mean in Matlab?

Comment: Did you mean [that other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1711943/296974)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no `**` operator in MATLAB.

```
>> 3**5
 3**5
  |
Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
```

That's [used in GNU/Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Arithmetic-Ops.html) as an alternative to power operator `^`. I think that program is tested on GNU/Octave and assumed to work also on MATLAB.

Comment: Yeah, I got the same result. Which is why I was wondering what the author tried to mean in that previous answer.