# MATLAB second-moments of a region

Tags: matlab, math, computer-vision, covariance

This is a follow-up question on the one below:

[Second moments question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532168/what-are-the-second-moments-of-a-region?lq=1)

MATLAB's regionprops function estimates an ellipse from a given set of 2d-points. This is done by using the image moments, they claim to use normalized second central moments, the formulas also follow what is suggested by the [wikipedia link on image moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment).
Effectively the covariance matrix of the region is calculated (in a slightly more efficient way) and then the square root of the eigenvalues of this matrix are calculated and put out as the major and minor axes - with one change: They are multiplied by a factor of 4.

Why?

Essentially, covariance estimation assumes a multivariate normal distribution. However, an arbitrary image region is most likely not normally distributed, I would rather expect a factor based on the assumption that data is uniformly distributed. So what is the justification for choosing 4?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found the answer: Factor 4 yields correct results for regions with an elliptical shape. For e.g. rectangular or non-solid regions, the estimated axis lengths are incorrect, and the error varies nonlinearly with changes in the region.